# Use mutate to get the last and first value on a number in dplyr for R

Tags: r, dplyr

So, I've got a dataset with a list of parties and the number of votes that they have recieved in an election . I'm interested in the first and last number of their vote totals. So if Labour got 2911 votes in the first observation, I want to create a third column that shows the first number, i.e: 2, and a fourth column that shows the last number, i.e: 1.

(Data below)

```
structure(list(var3 = c(2911L, 2292L, 2048L, 2038L, 2611L, 2308L
    ), var2 = c("Labour", "Labour", "Tower Hamlets First", "Labour", 
    "Labour", "Labour")), .Names = c("var3", "var2"), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

I've tried using mutate with tostring, but this gets all of the values and enters into each line, rather than just a single value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that we need the first and last digit as a single number i.e. for `2911`, we get the firstlast column as `21`.  This can be done with `sub`.  We use capture groups i.e. inside the braces to match the first and the last character in 'var3' (`(.)`) and replace with the capture groups (`\\1\\2`), then convert to numeric class if that is needed.

```
df1 %>% 
     mutate(firstlast = as.numeric(sub('^(.).*(.)$', '\\1\\2', var3)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!